# How to handle clicks on markers with google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-markers

With [`google_maps_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) how to set a handler for clicking markers on the map? (I am about the markers that Google, not me, added.)

Comment: the package itself offers the `Marker` object which has an `onTap` parameter!!

Comment: @omarhatem I know this. But this does not help to detect markers on the map that I did not create. There is a virtually infinite set of markers on the map. How do I know that one of them was clicked?